# Combining async and sync requests in python?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, request

I am trying to make a request to server A, where the response will be a list of requests, which I will make to server B.

Currently request to server A is just a simple sync request like this:

```
import requests

req = requests.get('https://server-a.com')
data = req.json()

list_of_requests = data['requests'] # requests for server B
```

Since `list_of_requests` can be a few thousand items long, I would like to use async to speed up the requests to B.

I've looked at several examples of async HTTP requests using aiohttp, such as from 
https://towardsdatascience.com/fast-and-async-in-python-accelerate-your-requests-using-asyncio-62dafca83c33

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import os

from aiohttp import ClientSession


GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:"
LIST_ISBN = [
    '9780002005883',
    '9780002238304',
    '9780002261982',
    '9780006163831',
    '9780006178736',
    '9780006280897',
    '9780006280934',
    '9780006353287',
    '9780006380832',
    '9780006470229',
]


def extract_fields_from_response(response):
    """Extract fields from API's response"""
    item = response.get("items", [{}])[0]
    volume_info = item.get("volumeInfo", {})
    title = volume_info.get("title", None)
    subtitle = volume_info.get("subtitle", None)
    description = volume_info.get("description", None)
    published_date = volume_info.get("publishedDate", None)
    return (
        title,
        subtitle,
        description,
        published_date,
    )


async def get_book_details_async(isbn, session):
    """Get book details using Google Books API (asynchronously)"""
    url = GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL + isbn
    try:
        response = await session.request(method='GET', url=url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(f"Response status ({url}): {response.status}")
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"An error ocurred: {err}")
    response_json = await response.json()
    return response_json


async def run_program(isbn, session):
    """Wrapper for running program in an asynchronous manner"""
    try:
        response = await get_book_details_async(isbn, session)
        parsed_response = extract_fields_from_response(response)
        print(f"Response: {json.dumps(parsed_response, indent=2)}")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Exception occured: {err}")
        pass

async with ClientSession() as session:
    await asyncio.gather(*[run_program(isbn, session) for isbn in LIST_ISBN])
```

However, all of the examples I have looked at start with the list of requests already defined. My question is, what is the proper pythonic way/pattern of combining a single sync request and then using that request to 'spawn' async tasks?

Thanks a bunch!